# Is it necessary to describe a girl or a boy as "young"?

Tags: adjectives

Is it necessary to describe a girl or a boy as "young"; e.g., the young girl wore a ribbon? By using the noun "girl" or "boy", is it not assumed that s/he is young?

Comment: Depends. I might describe an 11-year-old as a "boy" and a 3-year-old as a "young boy"; it depends on context.

Comment: Depends on the context.  (In the final analysis, is it "necessary" that you write this at all?)

Comment: "Young" and "old" are extremely relative. A 40-year-old might describe a 20-year-old as a "boy" and an 11-year-old as a "young boy."

Comment: And in the U.S. South you might describe a 45-year-old friend as an "old boy"—especially if you were near the same age yourself.

Answer (score 1):

If you describe a person as a "young girl" it means literally that the person is young in the speaker's estimation and a girl. So you can have basically any woman of reproductive age being called a young girl.

It ***could*** further mean that the person is a girl who is young compared to other girls. What I see journalists do is simply say the age of a person if it is important to know whether they are young or old, absolutely or relatively.

Comment: So I'm 66 next month.  What would I call Bruce Jenner?

Comment: It seems like 'girl' has become a kind of polite synonym of 'woman'. My late grandmother used to say 'Girls and I' about her and her friends.

Comment: @javaNoobs - "Girl" can be "acceptable" (not really "polite") or quite rude, depending on the circumstances.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say it is, as "girl" could refer to a year-old girl or a woman in her twenties, for example.

Comment: I remember a TV show "The Golden Girls" ... about some girls in their golden years (65 and up).

Comment: You call a year-old girl 'a baby-girl'